# Plotting grouped data in R along with their percentages

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

**My data is in this form**

```
df$new  df$y
0.5     A
0.0     D
1.0     D
1.0     M
1.0     A
1.0     MNY
1.0     NO
0.0     NO
1.0     PV
0.5     PV
1.0     S
0.0     S
```

**I just know basic plot, so i used**

```
barplot(df$new,names.arg = df$y)
```

But In the X-Axis there should be **unique values**, how can i get this?  also their **percentages**

*Percentages should be within them.* **Ex: A = 1.5/2 => 75%**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or,   you can do this in base R with `aggregate`.

```
Tab1 = aggregate(df$new, list(df$y), sum)
Tab1$x = Tab1$x / aggregate(df$y, list(df$y), length)$x
barplot(Tab1$x, names.arg=Tab1$Group.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're wanting with the percentages, exactly, but here's a solution that calculates those percentages in the dataframe and also creates the barplot of the count of each of the unique values of y. The key lies with `as.factor(y)`.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(new = c(0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5), 
                 y = c("A", "D", "D", "M", "A", "MNY", "NO", "NO", "PV"))

df$y<- as.factor(df$y)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(avg = mean(new))

df
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   y [6]
#>     new      y   avg
#>   <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>
#> 1   0.5      A  0.75
#> 2   0.0      D  0.50
#> 3   1.0      D  0.50
#> 4   1.0      M  1.00
#> 5   1.0      A  0.75
#> 6   1.0    MNY  1.00
#> 7   0.0     NO  0.50
#> 8   1.0     NO  0.50
#> 9   0.5     PV  0.50

ggplot(data = df) +
    geom_bar(aes(x = y))
```

Comment: This sums your percentages after calculating the percentage? Could you change your answer to calculate the percentage after summing?